# Plotting three charts in one figure

Tags: matlab

How can I plot a figure like this:[image]

My question is not about "subplot" function. I have one "x" array for x axis and three "y" arrays for y axis. I want to plot all (x,y) charts in a figure like above.

Comment: Can I ask?...why can't you use subplot?

Comment: You will have to offset the y-values appropriately for each plot, then manually interfere with the [y-axis tick marks and labels](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15HXQ/) and set their values.

Comment: @kitchenette because I think subplot can not do this job. As you can see all charts are in one box; Not three boxes in one figure.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use [`subaxis`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3696-subaxis-subplot). I wrote a sample code below:

```
x = 0:0.1:10;
spacing = 0.0;
subaxis(3,1,1,'Spacing',spacing);
plot(x,rand(size(x)),'k')
legend('D','Location','NorthWest')
ylim([-0.2 1])
set(gca, 'box','off')
set(gca,'XAxisLocation','top')

subaxis(2,'Spacing',spacing);
plot(x,rand(size(x)),'r')
legend('C','Location','NorthWest')
ylim([-0.2 1])
set(gca,'xtick',[],'box','off','xcolor','w')

subaxis(3,'Spacing',spacing);
plot(x,rand(size(x)),'b')
legend('B','Location','NorthWest')
set(gca, 'box','off')
```

[image]