# How to plot two figures in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot

I am implementing a clustering algorithm for `n` data points and I want to plot `n` data points in a figure before clustering and in another figure after clustering meaning that there should be two figures in same file with same data points.

My code is like:

```
X = 500*rand([n,2]);
plot(X(:,1), X(:,2), 'r.')                   1

%Some coding section here
```

After:

```
symbs = {'r+','g.','bv','m*','ko'};
hold on
for i = 1: length(I)
    plot(X(C==i,1), X(C==i,2), symbs{i})     2
end
```

I just want to plot (1) in one figure and (2) in another.

Comment: this post can be helpful for you: [Plotting three charts in one figure](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10642628/976870)

Answer (score 18):

Try [subplot](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/subplot.html):

```
figure;
subplot(1,2,1)
plot(firstdata)
subplot(1,2,2)
plot(seconddata)
```

This will create two axes areas within the same figure window... from your description, this is my best guess as to what you want.

Edit: From the comments below, here is what you are doing

```
n=50;
X = 500*rand([n,2]);
subplot(1,2,1); #% <---- add 'subplot' here
plot(X(:,1),X(:,2),'r.')
symbs= {'r+','g.','bv','m*','ko'}; 
subplot(1,2,2); #% <---- add 'subplot' here (with different arguments)
hold on
for i = 1: length(I)
plot(X(C==i,1),X(C==i,2),symbs{i})
end
```

If all you want is a second figure *window*, instead of doing `subplot` you can simply say `figure` in the place where I put the second call to `subplot` and a new figure window will be created.

```
figure; #% <--- creates a figure window
n=50;
X = 500*rand([n,2]);
plot(X(:,1),X(:,2),'r.') #% <--- goes in first window


symbs= {'r+','g.','bv','m*','ko'}; 
figure; #% <---- creates another figure window
hold on
for i = 1: length(I)
plot(X(C==i,1),X(C==i,2),symbs{i}) #% <--- goes in second window
end
```

Comment: Can you give some more information about *what* isn't working - edit your question with the code that isn't working, for example?

Comment: hello I have done updations  in my question .Plz check this one

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `figure` before each plot to get two plots in two separated figures

Comment: Can you elaborate on your answer? In its current form it is not very helpful.